# Is it impossible `create` a model with `validation: false` option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm using `create` method in a User model like this.

```
  def self.create_from_twitter_id(twitter_id)
    create!{|user| user.twitter_id = twitter_id }
  end
```

And I want to disable validation here, but I couldn't find out how to use `validation: false` option with `create` method. So I wrote like this.

```
def self.create_from_twitter_id(twitter_id)
  u = new { |user| user.twitter_id = twitter_id }
  u.save(validate: false)
  u
end
```

This is little redundant in comparison with first one.
Can't I use `create` a model with `validation: false` option?

Comment: It's not posible, but if you want to make it a oneliner, try: `new(twitter_id: twitter_id).tap{|u| u.save(validate: false)}`

Comment: I didn't know the `tap` method. It seems to be a little tricky, but quite useful. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it's a little tricky. It's good to know about it, but no to abuse of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, as of Rails 4.0.2.

If you look at the code for [`#save`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L56-L58)

```
def save!(options={})
  perform_validations(options) ? super : raise(RecordInvalid.new(self))
end
```

it expects the "skip validation" option to be passed when the method is called. But the definition of [`.create!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L35-L44) ignores such options.

```
object = new(attributes)
yield(object) if block_given?
object.save!
object
```